# Creating a Path Based on Multiple SlugFields in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, slug

I have a Django project based around creating tournaments and nesting specific objects within them. For instance, every tournament has multiple committees. When someone creates a tournament, I allow them to create a link with a `SlugField`. My code (so far) is as follows:

*models.py*

```py
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Tournament(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def _get_unique_slug(self):
        '''
        In this method a unique slug is created
        '''
        slug = slugify(self.name)
        unique_slug = slug
        num = 1
        while Tournament.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
            unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, num)
            num += 1
        return unique_slug

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = self._get_unique_slug()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class Committee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    belongsTo = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def _get_unique_slug(self):
        '''
        In this method a unique slug is created
        '''
        slug = slugify(self.name)
        unique_slug = slug
        num = 1
        while Committee.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
            unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, num)
            num += 1
        return unique_slug

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = self._get_unique_slug()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

*views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Tournament, Committee

def tournament_detail_view(request, slug):
    tournament = get_object_or_404(Tournament, slug=slug)    
    return render(request, 'tournament/detail.html', {'tournament': tournament})

def committee_detail_view(request, slug): 
    committee = get_object_or_404(Committee, slug=slug)    
    return render(request, 'committee/detail.html', {'committee': committee})
```

*urls.py*

```py
from . import views
from django.urls import path

app_name = 'tournament'
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.tournament_detail_view),
]
```

My question concerns `urls.py`. If a user creates a tournament called 'Zavala', they can currently access the website at `example.com/zavala`. However, if they create a committee named 'Cayde' under said tournament, there is no way for them to access the committee at `example.com/zavala/cayde`. The issue is that both of the sub-urls are slugs, and I'm not sure if Django can work with this. Is there a way to create a path that allows the user to go to the committee? I thought something along the lines of creating a function to test whether or not the tournament existed, but wasn't sure exactly how. Any tips? All I need is a working solution.

Comment: Django can most definitely have multiple slugs in urls. Is [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#example) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you think you can't have two slugs. You can:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.tournament_detail_view),
    path('<slug:tournament_slug>/<slug:committee_slug>/', views. committee_detail_view),
]
```

and now your committee_detail_view becomes:

```
def committee_detail_view(request, tournament_slug, committee_slug): 
    committee = get_object_or_404(Committee, slug=committee_slug, belongsTo__slug=tournament_slug)    
    return render(request, 'committee/detail.html', {'committee': committee})
```